# How to make drop down menu sticky

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I currently have a horizontal menu with a second horizontal drop down menubar directly underneath as you can see below. However the secondary dropdown menu bar underneath only stays for as long as the mouse hovers. Is there a way to make this secondary menu bar sticky so it stays visible until an option within it is clicked?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0sqL4cL7)

[image: Image of menu here]

```
   <li>
  <div><a href="link.html">link1</a>
  </div>
</li>
<li><a href="#">link2</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="link.html">bottom1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="link.html">bottom2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="link.html">bottom3</a>
        </li>
         <li><a href="link.html">bottom4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="link.html">bottom5</a></li>
        <li><a href="link.html">bottom6</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">link8</a>
  <ul>
        <li><a href="link.html">bottom1</a>
    </li>
        <li><a href="link.html">bottom2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="link.html">bottom3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="link.html">bottom4</a>
        </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

***MY CSS***

```
#menu, #menu ul {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#menu {
font-weight:400;
display: table;
width: 100%;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
top: -20px;
text-align: center;
left: -10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
font-size: 18px;
height: 20px;
z-index: 1101;
}
#menu.fixed {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
#menu li {
display: table-cell;
list-style: none;
padding-right: 10px;
left: 50px;
vertical-align:middle;
}
#menu > li:hover > ul {
background:#FFF;
display: block;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 3px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         0px 3px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
border-top:thin dotted #999;
top: 32px;
height: 30px;
}
#menu > li > ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
 text-align: center;

}
#menu li a {
display: block;
padding: 2px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: 400;
white-space: nowrap;
color: #333;

}
#menu li a:hover {
color: #0263B5;
font-size: 18px;
vertical-align: middle;
font-family: 'Lato', "sans-serif; 700;";
}
#menu li ul li {display: inline-block;
float:none; }
```

@Woodrow Barley this is the CSS I have directly taken from the broken menu

```
#menu {
font-weight:400;
display: table;
width: 100%;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
top: -20px;
text-align: center;
left: -10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
font-size: 18px;
height: 20px;
z-index: 1101;
}
#menu.fixed {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
#menu li {
display: table-cell;
list-style: none;
padding-right: 10px;
left: 50px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
#menu > li.active > ul {
background:#FFF;
display: block;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
border-top:thin dotted #999;
top: 32px;
height: 30px;
}
#menu > li > ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
 text-align: center;

}
#menu li a {
display: block;
padding: 2px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: 400;
white-space: nowrap;
color: #333;


}
#menu li a:hover {
color: #28B701;
font-size: 18px;
vertical-align: middle;
font-family: 'Lato', "sans-serif; 700;";
}
#menu li ul li {display: inline-block;
float:none; }
```

Comment: Pleasde add your entire code here http://jsfiddle.net/55a3jcnn/

Comment: just commenting to warn you that it will require some javascript.

Comment: @Akshay i think the author accidentally omitted the wrapping `<ul id="menu">` tag. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0sqL4cL7/

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow thats right i did sorry and JS is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, @Woodrow Barlow is right, you'll need JS to do this. try this: http://jsfiddle.net/0sqL4cL7/1/

I added this JQuery function

```
$('#menu > li').hover(function() {
      $( this ).addClass( "active" ).siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

and changed your

```
#menu > li:hover > ul {...}
```

to be

```
#menu > li.active > ul {...}
```

Comment: Hi @lee_gladding thanks for your help but when implemented on the website it is not working how it works in your JS Fiddle. for some reason the bottom menubar only appears when I click on the link in the main menu and hold down. As soon as I take my finger off of the mouse button the bottom menu bar disappears

Comment: @DanielNolan it sounds like you've used the pseudo-class `:active` instead of the class that @lee_gladding created `.active`. make sure you've used a period, and not a colon.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow i have added code to the bottom of the original post to show you where i am at.

Comment: Hi @DanielNolan after taking a look at the page quickly (in safari, chrome and FF) just now it seems to work. Guessing this is fixed now?